# Is there a way to use Promise.allsettled() in a way that only does one promise at a time with a delay?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

Basically, let me define a delay between resolving each promise.
Is there a built in way to do this, or do I have to use some sort of loop to go over an array?

I want to have a line of code that essentially does this:

```js
let hi = await Promise.allSettled(promiseArray, delayInMS);
```

I've tried putting a setTimeout function over the resolve, but it just sort of puts all of them in at once with a delay before returning:

```js
function makeBot([_u, _p]) {
    return new Promise(
        (resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => {
            var bot = mineflayer.createBot({
                username: _u,
                get password() { return config.cracked === true ? undefined : _p },
                get auth() { return config.cracked === true ? undefined : 'microsoft' },
                host: config.server,
                port: config.port,
                version: config.version
            });

            bot.on('error', (err) => reject(err));

            bot.once('spawn', () => {
                resolve(bot);
            });
        }, config.logininterval)
    );
};
//config.logininterval is set to number 1000

//later in the code...
function getRandomNameMap(amount) {
    let names = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= amount; i++) {
        let generatedName = config.crackedusername;
        if (config.userandomsuffix === true) {
            generatedName = generatedName + g.getRandomWords(1, config.randomprefixlength);
        };
        names.push(generatedName);
    };
    return names;
};
const usernames = getRandomNameMap(config.crackedamount).map(login => login.split(':'));
process.stdout.write(`Creating bots: `);
const botProms = usernames.map(makeBot);
bots = (await Promise.any(botProms)).map(({ value, reason }) => value || reason).filter(value => !(value instanceof Error));
```

Basically, I want the bots to login one after another with a delay.

Comment: `Promise.allSettled()` requires that you give it an array of promises, so it will not help you at all with sequencing operations or making a delay between them.  It is meant to track operations running in parallel.  Using a loop with `await` is the simplest way to sequence promise-based operations and you can also use `await` in the loop to create a delay between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've used @jfriend00's comment to solve this.
I did this:

```js
function makeBot([_u, _p]) {
    return new Promise(
        (resolve, reject) => {
            var bot = mineflayer.createBot({
                username: _u,
                get password() { return config.cracked === true ? undefined : _p },
                get auth() { return config.cracked === true ? undefined : 'microsoft' },
                host: config.server,
                port: config.port,
                version: config.version
            });

            bot.on('error', (err) => reject(err));
            bot.on('error', console.error);
            bot.on('kicked', console.error);

            bot.once('spawn', () => {
                process.stdout.write(`${bot.username} `);
                resolve(bot);
            });
        }
    );
};

//config.logininterval is set to number 1000

//later in the code...
function getRandomNameMap(amount) {
    let names = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= amount; i++) {
        let generatedName = config.crackedusername;
        if (config.userandomsuffix === true) {
            generatedName = generatedName + g.getRandomWords(1, config.randomprefixlength);
        };
        names.push(generatedName);
    };
    return names;
};
const usernames = getRandomNameMap(config.crackedamount).map(login => login.split(':'));
process.stdout.write(`Creating bots: `);
let botProms = [];
for (let username of usernames) {
    botProms.push(await makeBot(username));
}
bots = (await Promise.allSettled(botProms)).map(({ value, reason }) => value || reason).filter(value => !(value instanceof Error));
```

Basically, nest a promise but the innermost one iterates over all of the values with a delayed loop.